# How can I make the M2M relation to be a mandatory field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models Product and Category

```
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')

class ProductModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['categories', 'name', 'description']
```

By default Django doesn't throw a validation error if no category is introduced.

How can I make the M2M relation to be a mandatory field ?

Comment: You can add a `clean_categories` field to your forms, and enforce it contains at least one element. But a many2many *can* (by design) be empty.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added but Django seems to ignore it; it works for other fields

Comment: Can you share your `ModelForm` that you are using here?

Comment: A `required=True` probably should suffice here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem shared, if is posible I prefer to use something like clean, because I can do multiple checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not enforce this on the model layer, since a many-to-many relation constructs an extra table to represent the relation, and there is no (at least no dialect-invariant) way to specify that every id of one of the tables it refers to, should be present.

We can however enforce this in the form (for example a `ModelForm`), by making it `required=True`:

```
class ProductModelForm(EnhancedWidgetModelForm):
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['categories', 'name', 'description']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Product(models.Model):
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products', blank=False)
```